# How to export Python virtual environment with packages built from source?

Tags: python, linux, pip, virtualenv, pypi

i have python virtual environment with two packages built from source linked with CUDA11 and using GCC11. i want to use the same venv on another computer.

Is there any way to export the environment with all requirements and dependencies?
Does the other PC need CUDA11 and GCC11 installed and build again from scartch the packages on the other PC?

I tried to export the packages using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` but on the other PC it couldn't resolve the packages with conda nor pip.
and tried to recreate the same environment on the current PC with `pip install -r requirements.txt` but couldn't install the package i installed from source.

Comment: **couldn't install the package**... Did you get the error?

Comment: I get the error and I could solve it by building it again. but my goal is to export the virtual environment to be used on other PCs without needing to rebuild the two packages from the source with specific configs.

Comment: That's not the way the virtualenvs supposed to be used. They are supposed to be easily reproducible. You might need a `setup.py` script for this or docker.

Comment: Maybe you could try building (and sharing) a wheelhouse, with `pip wheel` for example.

Comment: @sinoroc could you give more information to give me a starting point?

Comment: Wheelhouse: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/repeatable-installs/#using-a-wheelhouse-aka-installation-bundles